# How to reverse each string element present in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array, say:

```
let noArray_leftOdd = ['0001101', '0011001', 
'0010011', '0111101'];
```

I want to reverse ***each string element*** in that array, i.e. the result required should be:

```
noArray_leftOdd = ['1011000', '1001100','1100100, '1011110'];
```

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you know how to reverse a single string?

Comment: have you hear of `Array.prototype.map` and googled how to reverse string in javascript?

Comment: Look at `map`. Or y'know, read anything about arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`: `split("")` each string into a character array, `reverse()` it, then `join("")` the reversed array back into a string:

```js
let noArray_leftOdd = ['0001101', '0011001', '0010011', '0111101'];

console.log(noArray_leftOdd.map(e => e.split("").reverse().join("")));
```

Comment: You could also do `Array.from(e)` instead of `split`.